Postgres logical replication, need to get only the changed column values, not all column values, on update event row
I am writing a client implementation of the Postgres logical replication protocol, but I encountered an unexpected behavior, in the DML UPDATE event
I always get all the values ​​of the table columns, even when the UPDATE changed only 1 column of this table.
I expected to get Byte1('u') in TupleData, this is a logical sign that the values ​​have not changed, but I always get Byte1('b') or Byte1('n') for all columns in the UPDATE event, so I cannot logically determine which columns have been changed.
How to fix this and why does this happen?

It happens because due to MVCC an UPDATE in Postgres is essentially a DELETE of the existing tuple and a INSERT of new tuple.

as far as I understand, only record identifiers and new changed values ​​are written to WAL, there is no point in storing unchanged values ​​in WAL, logical replication is essentially broadcasting WAL

As I understand it WAL just streams all statement actions as is without doing any editorializing as it is just binary output  This is why it can take some time to restore if there is not a recent basebackup to work off. Logical replication uses WAL as the source but then does decoding to get it into a form suitable for logical statements instead of binary ones. I have not gone any further then that into the details. I would suggest looking at the source here contrib/test_decoding. In particular pg_decode_change() in test_decoding. It might give you a hint at what to do.

I don't think you can do that with logical replication. You'd have to write your own logical decoding plugin that compares the old and the new tuple.

what is the point of Byte1('u') being defined in the logical replication protocol if this cannot be done?

At the moment, it is not possible to do this in the pgoutput plugin, I am surprised and disappointed, but this is the current implementation of the pgoutput plugin
